# Connect 1 USB cable to both PC and a travel adapter?

Tags: usb, adapter

I want to be able to have 1 cable to my phone which is both connected to my computer and a travel adapter so i can get faster charging. Would it work if i took the 2 data cables and connected them to 1 usb plug and took the power and ground cables and connected them to another so the power comes from the adapter and the data can be sent to and from the PC? If not is there another way to do it?

Comment: Completely depends on the phone. If it negotiates 500mA then it may only draw that much regardless of the power connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster charging? Maybe - or maybe not.

Certainly, if you modify a USB cable so that you are feeding 5V from an external charger that is good for 2 Amps or more, you have the **Capability** of getting charge into the phone faster.

The connections would be as follows: Gnd, D+, D- go to the computer as normal.  Gnd and V+ go to the charger or other high-current 5Vdc power source.

But the phone has to accept the amount of current that you can deliver.  And that's where things get tricky.

Many phones decide how much current they will accept from the charger based on how the D+ & D- lines are connected and what voltage is present on those lines.  If those lines are floating, the phone will assume that there is only 500mA available and adjust the charge rate accordingly.

Because you have connected the data lines to the computer for USB communications, there isn't any bias voltage on the data lines.  The phone will most likely query the computer to find out how much current is available.  Because the computer doesn't know about the extra power supply that you have added, it will probably tell the phone not to take more than 500mA (the normal maximum available current from a standard USB connector).

On the other hand - some phones decide how much charge current they will accept based on what voltage is applied to the V+ line.  Setting that voltage to about 5.5Vdc or 5.6Vdc allows the phone to charge at its maximum rate.

About the best that you can do is to try it and see what happens.  Provided that you don't mess up the wire connections or exceed 5.6 Vdc, you can't do any damage.

FWIW - I wouldn't try this unless I was fairly sure that the phone does determine charge current based upon incoming +V voltage.  Check the charger that comes with the phone - if the charger puts out 5.5 or 5.6 Vdc, you have a good chance of this working.

Comment: Nah, the original charger outputs 5V so it's probably not gonna work right? I think im gonna try to make some kind of switcher so I can switch between fast charging and having it connected to the computer. Thanks for the very informative answer!

Comment: Could you share your source of information about some phones deciding their charge functionality based on 5.6V of VBUS?

Comment: @PontusLiljeberg, how do you know that your original charger does not increase the initial 5V voltage, and doesn't negotiate higher voltage after connection to your phone? Do you know this for sure? Did you measure it with DMM or some power dongle?

Comment: Most newer phones use USB battery charger specification compatible methods. I would not try voltages bigger than 5.1V  with those - might fry stuff otherwise.